# Using the PostgreSQL JSONB type with Hibernate Reactive

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, quarkus, hibernate-reactive

I am migrating my Quarkus project from the classic Hibernate ORM to Hibernate Reactive and I faced a problem with JSONB field mapping.

Here is the entity:

```
@Entity
@TypeDef(name = JsonTypes.JSON_BIN, typeClass = JsonBinaryType::class)
class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "myEntityIdGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "myEntityIdGenerator", sequenceName = "my_entity_id_seq", allocationSize = 10)
    var id: Long? = null

    // Usage of a plain JsonNode instead of a mapped class is intentional, 
    // as the app receives a request with raw JSON data and should store it without any processing
    @Type(type = JsonTypes.JSON_BIN)
    @NotNull
    lateinit var jsonData: JsonNode
}
```

The project has the `io.quarkiverse.hibernatetypes:quarkus-hibernate-types:0.2.0` dependency to handle JSON types.

This code worked fine with blocking Hibernate API, but when trying to persist a `MyEntity` using the Hibernate Reactive, I get the following exception:

```
io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Parameter at position[1] with class = [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode] and value = [{"field1":"some value"}] can not be coerced to the expected class = [java.lang.Object] for encoding.
```

Is this a bug or custom types should be handled differently while using Hibernate Reactive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hibernate Types is not compatible with Hibernate Reactive.

But you have three options to map a Json with Hibernate Reactive:

1. Use `io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject`
2. Map it as String and use a converter
3. Create a UserType

### 1. JsonObject

Example with `io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject`:

```
    @Entity
    private static class EntityWithJson {

        ...

        private JsonObject jsonObj;

...
}
```

You can see a working example in the repository: [JsonTypeTest](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-reactive/blob/main/hibernate-reactive-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/reactive/types/JsonTypeTest.java)

### 2. Using a converter

Example using a converter:

```
class EntityWithJson {

        @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
        @Convert(converter = StringToJson.class)
        private String json;
...
}

@Converter
public class StringToJson implements AttributeConverter<String, JsonObject> {

    @Override
    public JsonObject convertToDatabaseColumn(String string) {
        if (string == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new JsonObject(string);
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(JsonObject dbData) {

        if (dbData == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return dbData.encodePrettily();
    }
}
```

You can see a working example in the repository: [JsonTypeTest](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-reactive/blob/main/hibernate-reactive-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/reactive/types/JsonTypeTest.java)

### 3. UserType

```
class EntityWithJson {


        @Type(type="org.example.Json")
        @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
        private JsonObject jsonObj;

}

package org.example

public class Json implements UserType {

   // ... Implementation left out for brevity
}
```

You can see a working example in the repository: [UserJsonTypeTest](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-reactive/blob/main/hibernate-reactive-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/reactive/types/UserJsonTypeTest.java)

Comment: Thank you for such an exhaustive answer. The `JsonObject` field approach seems OK to me, but, unfortunately, the `io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject` does not implement `Serializable`, so when I put the `@Cacheable` annotation on my entity class, I get this exception: `ClassCastException: class io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject cannot be cast to class java.io.Serializable`.

Comment: I think I would map it as a string in that case

Comment: I ended up implementing the `UserType`, handling the serialization via `assemble()` and `disassemble()` methods. Here is my solution: https://gist.github.com/Ultranium/2caaa4899ad117647f59abf690389dcd

Comment: Hello after trying the Use a converter i managed to make my application work but what about jsonB with Array? because this was just a simple json but when i try the same with array i keep failing

Comment: Would you be able to create a test case that I can run? I don't have a solution on top of my head

Answer (score 2):

To store a field with postgres type JSONB, we can use the annotation :

> @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)

This will automatically create the table column with JsonB data type.