# Storing JSON data as JSONB in PostgreSQL with Quarkus Panache is stored as escaped string

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm working on a project that uses Quarkus with Panache and PostgreSQL, and I'm trying to store JSON data as JSONB in the database. However, when I insert JSON data into the database, it gets escaped, and I'd like to store it without escaping in order to be able to query the JSON from the postgress.

Here's my code for inserting the JSON data:

```java
JsonObject jsonObject = Json.createObjectBuilder()
        .add("name", "John")
        .add("age", 30)
        .add("city", "New York")
        .build();
String jsonString = jsonObject.toString(); // Convert JsonObject to JSON String
return update("update OfferEntity o set o.items = ?1",  jsonString).onItem().transform(ignored -> offer);
```

However, in the PostgreSQL database, the inserted field looks like this:

```json
"{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":30,\"city\":\"New York\"}"
```

I want it to be stored as:

```json
{"name":"John","age":30,"city":"New York"}
```

This is my entity class for OfferEntity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "offering")
@Cacheable
@WithSession
public class OfferEntity extends PanacheEntityBase {

    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    @Column(name = "items", columnDefinition = "jsonb", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String items;

    public String getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(String items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

I'm using the latest Panache dependencies. How can I modify my code or configuration to store the JSON data as JSONB in PostgreSQL without escaping it? Please note that the framework can read the values from the database even if they are stored escaped but i also want to search them with query where this is not possible because the JSON is broken with all those escapes

**UPDATE**

I have also tried the following cases but the result is the same i get the values inside the database as

```json
"{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":30,\"city\":\"New York\"}"
```

First i tried this

```java
public class Item implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String city;//with getters setters
}
```

and OfferEntity class looked like this

```java
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    @Column(name = "items", columnDefinition = "jsonb", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Item items;

    public Item getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(Item items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
```

and I tried also make Items a map

```java
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    @Column(name = "items", columnDefinition = "jsonb", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Map<String, String> items;

    public Map<String, String> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(Map<String, String> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
```

Is this a hibernate bug? The version I use for hibernate is the 6.2.7 final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think hibernate doesn't support string [doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-mapping-json) as the standard mapping, try

```
public class OfferEntity extends PanacheEntityBase {

    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    private Map<String, String> items;
}
```

Or create your own POJO class

```
public class Items implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String city;
    //setters & getters
}
```

```
public class OfferEntity extends PanacheEntityBase {

    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    @Column(name = "items", columnDefinition = "jsonb", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Items items;
}
```

Refer to this [doc](https://thorben-janssen.com/persist-postgresqls-jsonb-data-type-hibernate/#using-hibernate-6s-standard-json-mapping)

UPDATED:

For hibernate-reactive using `io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject` refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73471277/using-the-postgresql-jsonb-type-with-hibernate-reactive)

Comment: I have tried creating a POJO of Items but the result inside the database is still the same also using the Map i get the same result everything is stored inside the databased using escapes "{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":30,\"city\":\"New York\"}". I will also add this to the question

Comment: Are u using `quarkus-hibernate-reactive-panache` or `quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache`?

Comment: I'm using quarkus-hibernate-reactive-panache

Comment: Then refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73471277/using-the-postgresql-jsonb-type-with-hibernate-reactive

Comment: Thanks a lot that actually worked and i let a comment to the person that gave the answer because it worked with basic json as i said in this example but it doesn't work with Array of json

Comment: @Theodosis I think it's reasonable to not support an array as a column even jonb does, you can work around it by wrapping your `items` array inside an object. Or create a new table `item` to own its data json object.

Comment: Okay im not sure exactly how i will do that because i will probably need to manipulate the converter class as well but i'm marking this as resolved because i asked for a simple json and the reference to the other post helped me alot

Comment: @phuongnq1995 Why is it reasonable not to support an array of objects, json was surely build for that [{},{}]. The new table might be a solution but that will lead to numerous "nested" tables and many to many relations and in any case the limitation of a language should not indicate the database design. Why is it so difficult to simply store and retrieve a non escaped json string in a jsonb field ? This is clearly a red flag in selecting Java/Hibernate/Quarkus. There must be a solution.

Comment: Hibernate was originally intended for use with relational databases, in terms of database normalization we should separate one-to-many relationship to another table even some of databases like Postgres supports arrays, 2D array. Otherwise, we can use a popular framework that supports JPA with NoSQL is EclipseLink, the reference implementation for JPA 3.

Comment: @phuongnq1995 i "hear" you and agree. One thing that might solve cases like these, as perhaps a global workaround, would be to map the jsonb as a byte array. Do you know if that's possible ? Also map as java.sql.Clob or java.sql.Blob ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work if the type was `JSONObject` instead of `String`

Comment: I have also tried this ```JsonObject jsonObject = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                    .add("name", "John")
                    .add("age", 30)
                    .add("city", "New York")
                    .build();
            OfferEntity f = new OfferEntity();

            f.setItems(jsonObject);
            return update("update OfferEntity o set o.items = ?2 where o.id = ?1", offer.getId(), f.getItems()).onItem().transform(ignored -> offer);
```
But inside the database, i get this 
```
"{\"name\":{\"valueType\":\"STRING\"},\"age\":{\"valueType\":\"NUMBER\"}}"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
@Convert(converter = ItemsConverter.class)
private JSONObject items;
```

being

```
@Converter
public class ItemConverter implements AttributeConverter<JSONObject, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(JSONObject data) {
        return data.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public JSONObject convertToEntityAttribute(String inputString) {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject r = new JSONObject();
        try {
            r = (JSONObject) parser.parse(inputString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            
        }
        return r;
    }
}
```

Comment: From what package do you get JSONParser and JSONObject?